# Manga where the MC has his ability blocked or chained by his own skill, but he broke after defeating a black dragon

Tags: story-identification, manga

In this manga there is a part where the childhood friend of the MC started to avoid him because in their academy he is deemed worthless and the lowest of the low.

Another part that I remember is his female samurai master. After their last training she passed away and he make a tomb for her.

He was always being admitted to the academy's infirmary because he's always wounded and the doctor always worries about him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

This is *[Ori of the Dragon Chain: "Heart" in the Mind](https://myanimelist.net/manga/138728)*.

> Solminati Academy is a prestigious school that harbors the dreams and hopes of ambitious students. Our story resolves a young man named Nozomu Bountis who entered the school for his lover's dream. As time went on, **his powers deadlocked and could no longer advance**, and his grades fell. Eventually, **his lover was stolen by his at the time best friend**. Heartbroken and lost on what to do next, he focused even harder on his training. Eventually, he meets an old woman, who triggers the catalyst to his growth. The future is uncertain, but gradually, his world changes.

The main character enters an academy to be with his childhood friend and lover. While at the academy, his growth deadlocks while she excels, leading to them drifting apart, culminating in a rumor spreading around the school that he cheated on her.

He has an ability that explicitly restricts his strength:

[image: chains]

He continues training by himself, in secret, despite being unable to become stronger within the academy. This is largely aided by an older female samurai he runs across;

[image: Teacher]

Chapter 8 consists of him fighting against a powerful dragon alongside his teacher. He briefly manages to overcome his ability restriction and slay it, and absorbs its powers. He doesn't actually fully remove his restriction, it's just that he obtains an incredible amount of power from the dragon that even his restrictive ability can't fully contain.

He does go to the infirmary at least twice and the nurse does worry about him, but it didn't sound like this was especially common.

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tag combination `Weak to Strong` and `Dragon/s`